# What language/wording is best to indicate the max character count on a text box has been exceeded?

Tags: forms, validation, language, wording

**Scenario**

After a user attempts to submit a form I am providing validation messages against any invalid fields. On one of those fields the user has gone over the max allowed character count.

**Example**

I have a text box called 'keyword' and it has a limit of 100 characters but they input 110, what is the best language to use to tell them what has gone wrong?

I have some examples below, **is there better language to use**?

- "Keyword must not exceed 100 characters"
- "Keyword must be no longer
  than 100 characters"
- "Keyword can be at most 100 characters"

Comment: Is the user made aware of that character limit before they submit, with a visible character counter perhaps?

Comment: @MattObee yes in this particular scenario (Windows Desktop app) they will see a balloon on blur of the field stating the problem. If they submit still without correcting the problem they will see a red error message below the invalid field. Both forms of message (balloon and red error text) will have the same text.

Comment: It's the actual language of the messages i'm deciding upon

Comment: I ask because that's an error state that I would normally try to avoid. If there's a character limit on a field, the user should be aware of that before they start composing and not just on blur. I'd display a running counter, much like the one that appears when writing a comment on SE. That said, you would of course still need to return an error message (like the one you're asking about) if they ignore that information.

Comment: @MattObee Have you ever seen an example of a character counter in Windows Desktop UI? I'm considering limiting the input of small text fields (try changing the computer description in control panel > system settings) as the user attempts to add more text they will get the balloon, and for larger text fields not limiting text input but having a character counter and showing the balloon on blur.

Comment: That approach sounds reasonable to me, although depending on the context I'd still want to tell the user about the limit on smaller fields before they start typing, unless they were unlikely to exceed it. For textareas, I can't think of any examples of character counters in native Windows UI but I agree with the approach you describe as long as it's clear to the user as soon as they've exceeded the limit and not only on blur.

Comment: If this really is about language, shouldn't this question be on the English language stackexchange then?

Comment: The first of your three choices seems the most quick to parse and understand. Just make sure you put the error message next to the associated field.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at how Twitter did.

1 - The clearly display the amount of characters available. The user know instantly if he is within the limit as he type. 
2 - If the user types beyond the limit, 2 visual cues are displayed (highlighting of the extra characters and character count is in red) also sumit is disabled.

I think they absolutely nailed it. Clear and easy for the user and bullet proof

[image: Twitter screen shot]

Comment: It would be better if they changed the focus colour too.

Answer (score 1):

I think any of recommendations for the error message are fine. I would choose the 3rd one you presented since its shorter and written in a positive way i.e. "It can be" vs "It can't be".

However, Matt Obee's question is valid and I don't think you understood it.
Instead of displaying an error message you should let the users know that limit before they even start writing.

Since you are imposing a limitation, you should either:

- Not let users write more than 100 characters. This way, when they reach that limit, their input will not be added, making them understand the limit
- Provide continuous feedback displaying (101/100 characters). This will let users know that have reached a limit but provide them a way to restructure their input to fit the limitation.

You can see an example of the second option when you make a comment in stackexchange.